# AngularJS - ng-show shows content while objects load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

I am using AngularJS with Firebase for a webapp. I am using Firebase as the user authentication. Each user has an email in their profile, and I want to display a warning to the user if they have not set their email. However, when a user is logged in and has correctly set their email, the warning flashes for a split second at the top of the page. I have figured out that this is because the user object does not fully load in the first few milliseconds so the warning is displayed even when the email is set. If I replace !(user.email) with a false variable the warning never shows up. The variable `user.email` is at the direct control of Firebase.

```
<div ng-show="user">
   <div class="row" ng-show="!(user.email)">
       <div class="col-md-12">
         <div class="alert alert-warning">
           Warning! You must...
         </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there any way I can get the warning not to display?

Comment: you don't need `()` to wrap `user.email` .

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi thanks

Comment: Does flashing happening for you all the time? If yes, post your complete HTML and controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have some mock value in `user.email`. This can be done via the controller or via `ng-init`.

Up on loading the user you should check the profile for email and set the `user.email` to that or delete the property.

---

If the `user` object is under the control of another script, you should use another scope variable for `ng-show`. You should initialize this variable with a mock value and update it with `user` object once the user is loaded.

Comment: user is automatically bound to the firebase, I tried using ng-init to set it to true, but it still flashed.

Comment: Use another scope variable for `ng-show` and update it when the user is loaded. Answer updated.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the `ng-hide` class to hide the element by default. Once your object loads, the `ng-show` directive will kick in and add or remove the `ng-hide` class as necessary.

```
<div ng-show="user">
   <div class="row ng-hide" ng-show="!(user.email)">
       <div class="col-md-12">
         <div class="alert alert-warning">
           Warning! You must...
         </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `ng-hide` class and methods to override certain behaviors are detailed [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow).

Comment: such a strange problem

Comment: @TheSabreSlicer That's probably because the `ng-hide` styles don't get loaded immediately either. Ideally, you should be inlining important styles like these. I'd still recommend just adding the class rather than messing around with the model.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at ng-init. You can use it to initialize a default on load.

Comment: I tried using it to initialize user.email = true, it still flashed. I think because user.email is bound to the firebase with 3-way databinding using AngularFire, I cannot really override it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="ng-hide" ng-show="user && !user.email" ng-cloak>
   <div class="row >
       <div class="col-md-12">
         <div class="alert alert-warning">
           Warning! You must...
         </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak